# Regex to match empty or any string except a specific string for request mapping

Tags: java, regex, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I need to do a request mapping for an URL, which would match an empty string, or any string except a specific string after a forward slash character: `/`.

The below regex matches any string after `/`, and ignores the specific string `"resources"`, but it is not matching empty string after that forward slash `/`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{page:(?!resources).*$}")
```

Current output:

```
/myapp/abc - matches and handles - ok
/myapp/resoruces - matches and ignores this URL - ok
/myapp/ - not matched <<<<<< expected to match!
```

What is wrong with this regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using spring 5 then use multiple mappings like this with an optional `@PathVariable`:

```
@RequestMapping({"/", "/{page:(?!resources).*$}"})
public void pageHandler(@PathVariable(name="page", required=false) String page) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(page)) {
        // root
    } else {
        // process page
    }
}
```

If you're using Spring 4 and you can leverage `Optional` class of Java 8:

```
@RequestMapping({"/", "/{page:(?!resources).*$}"})
public void pageHandler(@PathVariable("page") Optional<String> page) {
    if (!page.isPresent()) {
        // root
    } else {
        // process page
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect, first option worked, but if I have multi level path after /myapp then it is not getting matched, for example /myapp/abc/report not matched, I can have any number of paths after /myapp

Comment: @RequestMapping({"/", "/{page:(?!resources).*$}/**"}) is matching multilevel path after /myapp